# How does java generate R boxplot via RCaller?

Tags: java, r, boxplot, rcaller

I want to generate a R boxplot by using rcaller with java.
My code is :

```
try {
        RCaller caller = new RCaller();
        caller.setRExecutable("/usr/bin/R");
        caller.setGraphicsTheme(new DefaultTheme());

        RCode code = new RCode();
        code.clear();

        File file = code.startPlot();

        code.addRCode("boxplot((1:10),main=\"1-10\")");

        System.out.println(code.toString());
        code.endPlot();

        caller.setRCode(code);
        caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("boxplot(1:10),main=\"1-10\"");
        code.showPlot(file);
```

But it does not keep run on code`caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("boxplot(1:10),main=\"1-10\"");`

i try to use code below ,that can plot a R plot.what differences between them ?

```
try {
        RCaller caller = new RCaller();
        caller.setRExecutable("/usr/bin/R");
        caller.setGraphicsTheme(new DefaultTheme());

        RCode code = new RCode();
        code.clear();

        double[] numbers = new double[] { 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10 };
        code.addDoubleArray("x", numbers);

        File file = code.startPlot();
        System.out.println(file.toString());

        code.addRCode("plot.ts(x)");
        System.out.println(code.toString());
        code.endPlot();

        caller.setRCode(code);
        caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("plot.ts(x)");
        code.showPlot(file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line :

```
code.addRCode("boxplot((1:10),main=\"1-10\")");
```

By this :

```
code.addRCode("boxplot(c(1:10),main='1-10')");
```

Or as in the second example (the working one), you can give your x vector from java and replace this line:

```
caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("plot.ts(x)");
```

by

```
caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("boxplot(x)");
```

**PS: I dont' have java to test.**

Comment: Thanks for you answering!I tried your method ,it works!Thanks!But there is another question:if my code is :`code.addRCode("bp<-boxplot((data$" + "pp" + "),xlab=\"" + "pp"+ "\",main=\"" + "pp" + " boxPlots\")");`           ...The data is a data.frame.It does not work.Could you please help me...Thank you very much!

Comment: You should do something like `code.addRCode("paste0("bp<-boxplot((data$" , "pp" , "),xlab='" , "pp", "',main='" , "pp" , " boxPlots')")` But this suppose that you create your data.frame before : `code.addRCode("data <- data.frame(pp=1:10)")`

Comment: @YolandaWang You try to mix java and R code. Maybe you know some java, but I advise you seriously to get some R tutorial and get the R basics before trying to call it from another language.

Comment: i use paste,it works.not paste0...I looked for some detail about paste.It benefits me a lot!Thank you!

Comment: @YolandaWang `paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently.` from the help of paste...: I  don't see why it would work with paste and not with paste0...